# How to get the same random number for the same values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with IDs that are confidential and that can be repeated, and when distributing data I want the system to generate random numbers between 100,000-200,000 instead of those numbers, but in a way that assigns the same random number to repeating IDs.

Comment: "to assigns the same random number to repeating IDs" does not mean 'random', anymore... Please, if you cannot show us what you tried on your own, at least, edit your question and show us an example of what you want meaning...

Comment: If you want the same "random" number for the same value every time the system must remember the number it once gave, perhaps with a dictionary. If you want the same numbers again to be returned on every future use - meaning after the workbook was closed and reopened - the allocated "random" umbers must be saved with the workbook, perhaps in a `VeryHidden` worksheet.

Comment: Create a table of unique IDs.  Generate the random numbers against that list.  You'll need to take steps to ensure a unique mapping.  Then use a lookup to retrieve the "rabdom" alternative ID

Comment: Сonvenient to use hash function such as sha, md5 etc for this purpose

Comment: It is a database of companies with their tax numbers and revenues by activities. I need to send a spreadsheet without revealing which company it refers to, but that a summary of the revenue per company can be made. The numbers I get instead of the ID must be between 100-200,000 for database compliance.

Comment: @lambz then nothing has to be random. Start with 100 and increase by one. Then loop through your data take the first ID replace it in the entire data by 100. Then take the next ID replace it in the entire data by 101 (use a counter variable like `i` to increase every iteration). Do this in a loop and you are done. • Note that you somehow need to check if the current ID is already randomized or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
Option Explicit

Sub depersonalize()
    'Add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in Tools->References (VBE menu)
    Dim dict As New Dictionary, rng As Range, cl As Range, id As Long
    Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10")
    Randomize
    id = Fix(Rnd * 100)
    For Each cl In rng
        If dict.Exists(cl.Text) Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = dict(cl.Text)
        Else
            dict.Add cl.Text, id
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = id
            id = id + Fix(Rnd * 100)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Output**
[image]